# Populating dataframes in loop

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an elegant way to read one file at a time, do some preprocessing, and then merge into one big dataframe. 
The way I do it is here. I am sure there may be some other way to get rid of variable `i` here.

```
i=0
outdf = DataFrame()
for myfile in myfiles:
    tdf = read_csv(myfile) #Read
    #Do some annotations 
    tdf['Class'] = os.path.basename(myfile).split[0]
    ..............
    #-----------------
    if i == 0:
        outdf = tdf
    else:
        outdf = concat([outdf, tdf])
    i = i +1
```

Comment: AFAIK you don't need i and the if clause in that loop as well. Just use `outdf = concat([outdf, tdf])`. In the first iteration it will do the concatenation with the empty dataframe so it will return the same dataframe.

Comment: At some point I started doing this kind of funny things. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate the DataFrames on each iteration, as `concat` can concatenate multiple DataFrames.  Just store each individual DataFrame in a list, and concatenate at the end.

```
outdf = []
for myfile in myfiles:
    tdf = read_csv(myfile)
    #Do some annotations 
    tdf['Class'] = os.path.basename(myfile).split[0]
    ..............
    #-----------------
    outdf.append(tdf)

outdf = concat(outdf)
```

Comment: This will also be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate.

```
    outdf = DataFrame()
    for i, myfile in enumerate(myfiles):
       tdf = read_csv(myfile)
       tdf['Class'] = os.path.basename(myfile).split[0]
       if i == 0:
           outdf = tdf
       else:
           outdf = concat([outdf, tdf])
```